# Hive: assert/test that two columns always contain the same values

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to check that two columns in my Hive table with the same type always have the same values (potentially for a subset).

Someone [asked a similar question previously](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201105.mbox/%3CBANLkTimdcg+oicwa-Z7Q2D6+=7Z85D_3Qg@mail.gmail.com%3E), but I do not think that it was conclusively answered there. I am basically looking for a `sum(col == col2)` type semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select sum(case when !(col1=col2 ) then 1 else 0 end) as sum_not_equal 
from
(select 20 col1, 20 col2
union all 
select 10 col1, 10 col2
)s
```

or

```
count(case when !(col1=col2 ) then 1 end)
```